# Number of permutations of multiset

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've tried to solve this problem with some logic and combinatorics, but couldn't find a solution.

Question is:

> How many permutations of multiset $\{1^{200}, 2^{200},\cdots
> > ,9^{200}\}$ that start with exactly three twos (i.e., $222\cdots$) and
> end with exactly three sevens (i.e., $\cdots 777$) are there?

I've tried to figure out which number can be last, and found out that $3^{200}$ and $7^{200}$ are possible solutions, but I am not sure how to check if they both end with $777$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried to figure out which number can be last, and found out that 3²⁰⁰ and 7²⁰⁰ are possible solutions, but I am not sure how to chech If they both ends with 777.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, there are $2000$ positions to fill, $200$ of each digit.  We know that the first three positions are twos and the last three positions are sevens.  That means there are $1994$ positions left to fill, of which $200$ each are ones, threes, fours, fives, sixes, eights, and nines and $197$ each are twos and sevens.  Think about how you can fill those positions with the digits you have not yet used.